# Android Как проверить есть ли в строке символы с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: android, регулярные-выражения

Как я могу получить bolean из проверки регулярным выражением строки ::10322018** на наличие одного+ : и нескольких цифр ?

Comment: Приведите пример, какие строки должны возвращать true, а какие не должны

Comment: ::103 =true, ::(только двоеточие)=false,  552266::=false ,

Comment: мне требуется чтобы или в начале было :10322018 или 10322018* в конце звездочка

Comment: Не понятно - должна быть группа любых чисел в любом количестве и либо в начале одно `:` либо в конце одна `*` - так: `boolean math = string.matches("(:\\d+)|(\\d+\\*)");`?

Comment: да, минимум одно `:` или минимум одна на конце `*`, а седине несколько цифр.   `:` и  `*` это экраны в блютуз передаче, мне нужно проверить что строка пришла неполная , а не просто эфирный мусор